# Facebook Login via Safari or FB App doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

This method works perfectly fine when the user is logged in to Facebook in iOS8 Settings.

But if he's not, it attempts login using Safari or the Facebook iOS app and once the user get redirected back to the app it simply shows this logged message, instead of logging in the user.

And I'm using the Parse.com SDK.

**Message logged**

```
NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
```

**Facebook Login Method**

```
-(void)loginButtonPressed
{
      [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

        NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_about_me"];

        // Login PFUser using Facebook
        [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

            if (!user) {
                NSString *errorMessage = nil;
                if (!error) {

                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                    errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
                }

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                                message:errorMessage
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
                [alert show];

            } else {
                if (user.isNew) {
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
                } else {
                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
                }
               // [self _presentUserDetailsViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line in `AppDelegate.m` fixed the problem.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```